# Cannot Get This Code To Compile, any ideas?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This code doesn't seem to want to compile. I'm sorta new to Java Programming. Any help would be much appreciated. The error says that it can't find symbol.

```
package addressbookexample1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddressBookExample1 {

    private Contact[] friends; 
    private int numfriends; 

    // Create an empty AddressBook
    public AddressBookExample1() {
        friends = new Contact[10];
        numfriends = 0;
    }

    // Add a contact that's passed in as a parameter.
    public void addContact(Contact c) {
        friends[numfriends] = c;
        numfriends++;
    }

    // Print out info on all contacts using method Contact class.
    public void printContacts() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numfriends; i++) {
            friends[i].printContact();
        }
    }

    // Returns the number of friends currently in AddressBook
    public int numContacts() {
        return numfriends;
    }


    private int haveContact(String s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numfriends; i++) {
            if (friends[i].getName().equals(s)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Deletes a contact with name
    public void deleteContact(String s) {

        int place = haveContact(s);
        if (place >= 0) {
            friends[place] = friends[numfriends - 1];
            numfriends--;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Instantiate AddressBook object
        AddressBook blackbook = new AddressBook();

        // Menu driven loop.
        menu();
        int choice = stdin.nextInt();

        while (choice != 5) {


            if (choice == 1) {

                if (blackbook.numContacts() < 10) {

                    //Reads in all appropriate information.");
                    System.out.println("Enter your friend\'s name:");
                    String name = stdin.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their age.");
                    int age = stdin.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their phone number.");
                    int number = stdin.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the birthday, month on one line, then day on the next.");
                    int mon = stdin.nextInt();
                    int day = stdin.nextInt();


                    blackbook.addContact(new Contact(name, age, number, mon, day));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, can not add anyone, your blackbook is full.");
                }
            } 
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("What is the name of the contact you want to delete?");
                String name = stdin.next();
                blackbook.deleteContact(name);
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                System.out.println("You have " + blackbook.numContacts() + " contacts.");
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                blackbook.printContacts();
            } else if (choice != 5) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that was an invalid menu choice, try again.");
            }

            menu();
            choice = stdin.nextInt();
        }

    }

    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("1.Add a new contact to your address book.");
        System.out.println("2.Delete a contact from your address book.");
        System.out.println("3.Print out the number of contacts you have.");
        System.out.println("4.Print out information of all of your contacts.");
        System.out.println("5.Quit.");
        System.out.println("Enter your menu choice:");
    }
}
```

Compiler Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AddressBook
  location: class addressbookexample1.AddressBookExample1
    at addressbookexample1.AddressBookExample1.main

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error message. Line numbers and error codes are extremely helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Can you copy the compile error?

Comment: What symbol does it say it can't find?

Comment: Can you post the full error / stack trace?

Comment: Can you please provide the error(s) that you're getting?  Also, this seems like homework, if it is could you please tag it as such?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AddressBook
  location: class addressbookexample1.AddressBookExample1
 at addressbookexample1.AddressBookExample1.main

Answer (score 2):

You defined this as AddressBookExample1, but you're trying to instantiate AddressBook.

```
// Instantiate AddressBook object
AddressBook blackbook = new AddressBook();
```

Change to

```
AddressBookExample1 blackbook = new AddressBookExample1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Contact class is missing. I assume this is also part of the example and you need to include the source for it in your build as well.

Comment: This is just an example I am trying to figure out. How do I define that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Look for Contact.java somewhere else in the example code. Or write a new one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the Contact class

Comment: This is just an example I am trying to figure out. How do I define that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it looks like Contact might not be available.  Try compiling both Contact.java and this class at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the class AddressBook, but you have defined AddressBookExample1.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an example, there should be other code from where the sample is, that defines the "Contact" and "Addressbook" classes. You should make sure that you enter the sample code exactly as provided. Maybe you've changed the name of the AddressBook class to AddressBookExample1?